# Datetime "fromtimestamp()" ignores inheritance if timezone is not None

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, inheritance

I created a class inheriting from [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime).

While creating a new instance using the classmethod [`fromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) it seems to work, **except** if I provide a `timezone` object. In such case, the returned object is of base type `datetime`.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime, timezone

class MyDatetime(datetime):
    pass

MyDatetime.fromtimestamp(time.time())
# MyDatetime(2018, 11, 30, 18, 8, 36, 418105)
# <class '__main__.MyDatetime'>

MyDatetime.fromtimestamp(time.time(), tz=timezone.utc)
# datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 30, 17, 8, 50, 667385, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
# <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

This seems surprising. I don't see any mention of such weird behavior in the documentation, am I missing something or is it a Python bug?

Comment: Just to concur, I'm also seeing this on my CPython3.7.1 build.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Thanks, I was wondering if that could have been fixed with Python 3.7 (I use 3.6) as I saw mentions of "fromtimestamp" in the issue trackers. I will definitely open a new one, then.

Comment: Opened issue: [#35364](https://bugs.python.org/issue35364)

Answer (score 1):

**[Cross Posting from Python Bug Tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue35364)**

It's a side effect of a date arithmetic operation performed while setting timezone.

- while passing tz info to datetime it invokes [tz.fromutc()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3df85404d4bf420db3362eeae1345f2cad948a71/Lib/datetime.py#L1593)
- followed by a datetime arithmetic [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3df85404d4bf420db3362eeae1345f2cad948a71/Lib/datetime.py#L2188)
- which eventually leads to building a new datetime object [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3df85404d4bf420db3362eeae1345f2cad948a71/Lib/datetime.py#L1997-L2000)

I'm not sure if its an expected behaviour

Comment: Thanks for your investigation! :)